# In MOSS, can you add a Publishing Image field to an Announcements list?

Tags: sharepoint, list, moss

Using Sharepoint MOSS 2007, I want to add a Publishing Image field to my Announcements list which I am using for news. Is this possible? Should I make a new list type that instead inherits from Publishing Page?

Ultimately, I want to display the contents of this list using a Content Query Web Part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a Publishing column directly from a non-publishing list. Instead, create it as a site column and then choose "Add from existing columns" on the list content type definition. You will then be able to add a Publishing Image or Publishing Hyperlink.

Hope this helps someone.